# Issue creating a Google Analytics "Returning Users" metric in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Taking what has been described on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/87523

As well as my own understanding, I've come up with what I think would be considered "Returning Users"

1.First a query to show users who had their first "latest visit" within a two year time period:

```
SELECT
  parsedDate,
  CASE
  # return fullVisitorId when the first latest visit is between 2 years and today
    WHEN parsedDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND CURRENT_DATE() THEN fullVisitorId
  END fullVisitorId
FROM (
  SELECT
    # convert the date field from string to date and get the latest date
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
      MAX(date)) parsedDate,
    fullVisitorId
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
    # only show fullVisitorId if first visit
    totals.newVisits = 1
  GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId)
```

2.Then a separate query to select some fields within a specific date range:

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
    date) parsedDate,
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  totals.newVisits,
  totals.visits,
  totals.bounces,
  device.deviceCategory
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = "20180118"
```

3.Joining these two queries together to find "Returning Users"

```
SELECT
q1.parsedDate date,
COUNT(DISTINCT q1.fullVisitorId) users,
# Default way to determine New Users
SUM(q1.newVisits) newVisits,
# Number of "New Users" based on my queries (matches with default way above)
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(q2.parsedDate < q1.parsedDate, NULL, q2.fullVisitorId)) newUsers,
# Number of "Returning Users" based on my queries
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(q2.parsedDate < q1.parsedDate, q2.fullVisitorId, NULL)) returningUsers
FROM (
(SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
    date) parsedDate,
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  totals.newVisits,
  totals.visits,
  totals.bounces,
  device.deviceCategory
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = "20180118") q1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
  parsedDate,
  CASE
  # return fullVisitorId when the first latest visit is between 2 years and today
    WHEN parsedDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND CURRENT_DATE() THEN fullVisitorId
  END fullVisitorId
FROM (
  SELECT
    # convert the date field from string to date and get the latest date
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
      MAX(date)) parsedDate,
    fullVisitorId
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
    # only show fullVisitorId if first visit
    totals.newVisits = 1
  GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId)) q2
ON q1.fullVisitorId = q2.fullVisitorId)
GROUP BY
date
```

**Results in BQ**

[image: BigQuery Results]

**Un-sampled new/returning visitors split by Users report for the same period in GA**

[image: new/returning visitors split by Users report GA]

**Questions/Issues:**

1. Given that `newVisits` (default field) and `newUsers` (my calculation) is giving the same results which is inline with the GA report New Visitor Users. Why is there mismatch of GAs Returning Visitor Users and my calculation of `returningUsers` in BQ? can these two even be compared, what am I missing?
2. Is my approach the most efficient and less verbose way of going about this?
3. Is there a better way to get the figures, something I'm missing?

**SOLUTION**

Based on Martin's answer below, I managed to create the "Returning Users" metric/field within the context of the query I was running:

```
SELECT
  date,
  deviceCategory,
  # newUsers - SUM result if it's a new user
  SUM(IF(userType="New Visitor", 1, 0)) newUsers,
  # returningUsers - COUNT DISTINCT fullvisitorId if it's a returning user
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(userType="Returning Visitor", fullvisitorid, NULL)) returningUsers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) users,
  SUM(visits) sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    totals.visits,
    device.deviceCategory,
    IF(totals.newVisits IS NOT NULL, "New Visitor", "Returning Visitor") userType
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20180118` )
GROUP BY
  deviceCategory,
  date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics uses approximations for users (fullvisitorid) - even if it says "based on 100%". You get better user numbers when using an unsampled report.

Another thing to mention: fullvisitorids are taken into consideration even if `totals.visits != 1`, while sessions are only counted where `totals.visits = 1`

Also users are double-counted if they where new and then returned. Meaning, this should give you correct numbers:

```
SELECT
  totals.newVisits IS NOT NULL AS isNew,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) AS visitors,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20180214`
GROUP BY
  1
```

If you want to avoid double counting you can use this, where a user is counted as new even if she returned:

```
WITH
  visitors AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid,
    -- check if any visit of this visitor was new - will be used for grouping later
    MAX(totals.newVisits ) isNew, 
    SUM(totals.visits) as sessions
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20180214`
  GROUP BY 1
  )

SELECT
  isNew IS NOT NULL AS isNew,
  COUNT(1) AS visitors,
  sum(sessions) as sessions
FROM
  visitors
GROUP BY 1
```

Of course these numbers match with GA only in totals.

Comment: Thanks Martin, detailed explanation. Those calculations will be handy! I wanted to be able to have a field with the number of returning users. Having said that, based on your explanation and calculations, I managed to do it. Will update my post with this as well.